# Monthly retention rate showing 0 for January of new year

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Here is my code for calculating monthly retention rates. The issue is that Monthly retention rate is showing 0 for January of new year.

```
WITH monthly_user_counts AS (
  SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date)) AS year,
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date)) AS month,
    user_pseudo_id
  FROM
    `table`
),
returning_users AS (
  SELECT
    curr.year,
    curr.month AS current_month,
    COUNT(DISTINCT prev.user_pseudo_id) AS returning_user_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT curr.user_pseudo_id) AS total_users
  FROM
    monthly_user_counts curr
  LEFT JOIN
    monthly_user_counts prev
  ON
    curr.year = prev.year AND curr.month - 1 = prev.month AND curr.user_pseudo_id = prev.user_pseudo_id
  GROUP BY
    curr.year, current_month
),
inter as (
SELECT
  year,
  current_month,
  returning_user_count,
  total_users,
  (returning_user_count * 100.0 / total_users) AS monthly_return_percentage
FROM
  returning_users
ORDER BY
  year, current_month
)
,
inter2 as (
SELECT
  inter.*,
  CASE 
    WHEN current_month = 1 THEN 'January'
    WHEN current_month = 2 THEN 'February'
    WHEN current_month = 3 THEN 'March'
    WHEN current_month = 4 THEN 'April'
    WHEN current_month = 5 THEN 'May'
    WHEN current_month = 6 THEN 'June'
    WHEN current_month = 7 THEN 'July'
    WHEN current_month = 8 THEN 'August'
    WHEN current_month = 9 THEN 'September'
    WHEN current_month = 10 THEN 'October'
    WHEN current_month = 11 THEN 'November'
    WHEN current_month = 12 THEN 'December'
    ELSE 'Unknown'
  END AS month,
  from inter)

  select year,month,total_users,returning_user_count, monthly_return_percentage from inter2
```

The output is mostly correct I think but The main problem is the 0 value in January for returning user count

Update: based on Josh's answer, I have updated my code as follows:

```
WITH monthly_user_counts AS (
  SELECT
    PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',event_date) AS obs_date,
    DATE_SUB(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',event_date), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS prev_date,
    user_pseudo_id
  FROM
    `rayn-deen-app.analytics_317927526.events_*`
),
returning_users AS (
  SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM curr.obs_date) AS year,
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM curr.obs_date) AS month,
    COUNT(DISTINCT prev.user_pseudo_id) AS returning_user_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT curr.user_pseudo_id) AS total_users
  FROM
    monthly_user_counts curr
  LEFT JOIN
    monthly_user_counts prev
  ON
    curr.obs_date = prev.prev_date AND curr.user_pseudo_id = prev.user_pseudo_id
  GROUP BY
    year, month
),
inter as (
SELECT
  year,
  month,
  returning_user_count,
  total_users,
  (returning_user_count * 100.0 / total_users) AS monthly_return_percentage
FROM
  returning_users
ORDER BY
year, month
)

SELECT * FROM inter
```

Now the issue of retention rate of January being equal to zero is not there, but retention rates are quite low compared to those given by my original query. Can somebody please let me know if the query I am using now is logically sound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because the comparison month in that case has a different YEAR, then you are missing that join for January to December.

I would avoid parsing the year and month separate, and instead calculate the `obs_date` and `prev_date` as a date type, and you can use datediff to subtract a 1 month interval from the `obs_date`.

Then in your join you can change it to `curr.prev_date = prev.obs_date`.

Something like this (I might have mistakes, this was coded blindly).

```
WITH monthly_user_counts AS (
  SELECT
    event_date AS obs_date,
    DATE_DIFF(event_date, INTERVAL -1 MONTH) AS prev_date,
    user_pseudo_id
  FROM
    `table`
),
returning_users AS (
  SELECT
    obs_date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT prev.user_pseudo_id) AS returning_user_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT curr.user_pseudo_id) AS total_users
  FROM
    monthly_user_counts curr
  LEFT JOIN
    monthly_user_counts prev
  ON
    curr.obs_date = prev.prev_date AND curr.user_pseudo_id = prev.user_pseudo_id
  GROUP BY
    curr.obs_date
),
inter as (
SELECT
  obs_date,
  returning_user_count,
  total_users,
  (returning_user_count * 100.0 / total_users) AS monthly_return_percentage
FROM
  returning_users
ORDER BY
  obs_date
)
```

Comment: can you pls provide sample code, I have a tight deadline and dont know how to fix this.

Comment: Thanks, but this gives a return percentage for each date. I want it to be aggregated for each unique year-month combination.

Comment: I have updated my question based on your response, can you please go over it, if you approve, then I will accept your answer. Thanks so much Josh, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is if your event_date is not always on the first of the month or something like that. Try adding a DATE_TRUNC to both obs_date and prev_date in the very first CTE and see if that changes anything